# Создать новый android проект в eclipse на основе существующего

Tags: android, eclipse

Есть большой проект, необходимо создать новый такой же с немного другим пакетом (вместо xxx.yyy.zzz xxx.yyy.kkk) и другим названием устанавливаемого android приложения. Как это сделать максимально просто?

Comment: правой кнопкой на пакете Refactor... Rename... оно?

Answer (score 3):

Имя пакета можно в манифесте поменять и имя приложения там же.

Answer (score 0):

Копируем проект целиком, потом добавляем его в eclipse. Через refactoring -> rename меняем название пакет. И не забываем поменять в манифесте название пакета.